# angularjs templateUrl in WebContent

Tags: angularjs, jakarta-ee, angularjs-directive

I am deplying my angular app in java dynamic web project, directory map:

```
->WebContent
---->javaScript
------>directives
index.html
```

and in my directives folder I have form directive:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
    app.directive('formDirective', formDirective);

function formDirective() {

    var directive = {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: 'formDirective.html', //the request
        scope: {
        },
        controller: FormControllerDir,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true
    };
    return directive;
}
function FormControllerDir() {
    console.log('FormController');
}
```

and `formDirective.html` is placed under the same dir, but angular search for the file under root:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/P2P/formDirective.html 404 (Not Found)
```

P2P is my project name, how do I change it to:

```
http://localhost:8080/P2P/JavaScript/directives/formDirective.html
```

Comment: maybe add `/` in front `templateUrl: '/formDirective.html'`

Comment: what about ./formdirective.html

Comment: almost, it redirect to sub folder, yes but this is the way, posting answer.

Answer (score 0):

So it was simple just add the full path form context -

`templateUrl: 'JavaScript/directives/formDirective/formDirective.html'`